# Kafka Broker - Is it same as Zookeeper? or KafkaProducer is the broker?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, messagebroker

There are multiple code examples available (One of such is [here](https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-producer-and-consumer-example)) where KafkaProducer and KafkaConsumers are implemented and can be started separately.

I was trying to find the code that starts the broker?

I think Zookeeper is not the KafkaBroker, as Zookeeper is for some other purpose  .. managing clusters states.

While creating the KafkaProducer we pass in property like

```
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, IKafkaConstants.KAFKA_BROKERS);
```

Does that mean the KafkaProducer it self start the broker?

Comment: Brokers is a part of infrastructure. And in most cases should not be started in the code (if it is not for tests, of course).

Answer (score 5):

The Zookeeper manages the co-ordination and synchronisaton of the Kafka brokers, and they are separate components.

The Producer does not start the broker. The Producer and Consumer are client-side components that *connect to* one or more Kafka brokers, and produce/consume data to and from the cluster of brokers.

The Kafka broker is generally started by running `kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh kafka/config/server.properties`, which will start one Kafka broker with the properties defined in the `server.properties` file.

Answer (score 3):

Is important to begin have so clear the concepts:

**Kafka broker** = One instance of kafka started, i mean start the application  download from (https://kafka.apache.org/downloads)

**Zookeeper** = Effectively is a coordinator for cluster in this specific case you can start up many instance on kafka with zookeeper and take a cluster.

**Kafka Producer** = Any application (implement kafka libraries) that is in charge of send message to specific kafka topic, some like queue.

**Kafka consumer** = Any application (implement kafka libraries) that is in charge of get messages of kafka cluster and process it.

For start kafka you first set a system environment (optional), and then execute this commands :

## ---- first start zookeeper

nohup zookeeper-server-start.sh $KAFKA_HOME/config/zookeeper.properties &

## ----- then istart kafka

nohup kafka-server-start.sh $KAFKA_HOME/config/server.properties &